# Storing Where clause in a table for a status

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Consider the following tables:

```
Item(id, dueDate)

DueStatus(id, code, whereClause)
```

The DueStatus table has the following values:

```
1/OVERDUE/'dueDate < getdate()'
2/DUE/'dueDate = getdate()'
```

The idea would be to store the where clause in the table, and then use it to create dynamic SQL for execution for all the different statuses.

Is there a benefit to doing this in this style, as opposed to just hand writing the queries?

The goal would be to be able to add a DueStatus such as `3/NEXTFIVEDAYS/'dueDate = dateadd(day,datediff(day,-5,@currentDate),0)'` without having to change the Stored Procedure.

I have not gone down this road before, and wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something important.

Comment: Storing where clauses like this is a good sign that the design is less than ideal. I have a feeling you suspect that yourself which is why you are asking.

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange. Data should be stored in a table, not business logic. Business logic belongs in the application which might just be something as simple as a view, stored proc, excel file, etc... You can do dynamic sql in a stored proc and pass in parameters and all that so it really makes sense to concentrate your efforts back on the proc.

Comment: Are you expecting the dueStatus  to change a lot? usually, status tables as a fixed, very low number of rows. Isn't that the case here as well?

Comment: And then there are execution plans. The only way to be sure you're getting a good plan with each run will be to `RECOMPILE` every time, since the `WHERE` clause will always be up in the air. That's overhead you don't need.

Comment: I have the feeling that the operation written in the `whereClause` field depends of the content of the `code` field. If you want to keep it purely SQL side, I would use stored procedure with `CASE code WHEN 'OVERDUE' THEN some query WHERE dueDate < getdate()` and so on...

Comment: These expressions look like they can all be unified to one of the form `WHERE dueDate <= DATEADD(..., DATEDIFF(...,))`, with zeroes and/or offsets in appropriate spots. If you can do that, than rather than storing the clause as-is (which is a terrible idea, as others have elaborated) you can just store the parameters to the clause, which at the very least avoids a host of problems with changing the query itself.

Comment: I agree with others that logic and data should not be mixed. If, by any reason, you want to go to a similar road why not create a function that will implement that logic instead of storing SQL code in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do that.  The problem comes on updating the where column:

1. What if the column name changes?
2. What if you want to add another condition to your where clause? Then you have to go row by row or go the root of what you are trying to run initially anyway.
3. How many conditions does your where clause have?

See above comments for more reasons not to.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be an interesting challenge for a dynamic status based on the difference between two dates. I came up with this. While probably not 100% for most use cases, maybe it's something you can work with.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [DueDate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO dbo.Items(ID, DueDate) VALUES (1, '12/1/2018')
INSERT INTO dbo.Items(ID, DueDate) VALUES (2, '12/2/2018')
INSERT INTO dbo.Items(ID, DueDate) VALUES (3, '12/6/2018')
INSERT INTO dbo.Items(ID, DueDate) VALUES (4, '12/6/2018')
INSERT INTO dbo.Items(ID, DueDate) VALUES (5, '12/10/2018')
INSERT INTO dbo.Items(ID, DueDate) VALUES (6, '2/1/2019')
INSERT INTO dbo.Items(ID, DueDate) VALUES (7, '1/1/2013')
INSERT INTO dbo.Items(ID, DueDate) VALUES (8, '12/5/2018')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Statuses](
    [DayDifference] [int] NULL,
    [StatusText] [varchar](32),
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Statuses(DayDifference, StatusText) VALUES(0, 'On Time')
INSERT INTO dbo.Statuses(DayDifference, StatusText) VALUES(1, '1 Day Late')
INSERT INTO dbo.Statuses(DayDifference, StatusText) VALUES(5, '5 Days Late')

;WITH Data AS (
    SELECT  i.ID AS ItemID,
            i.DueDate,
            DATEDIFF(DAY, i.DueDate, GETDATE()) AS DayDifference
    FROM    dbo.Items i
    WHERE   DATEDIFF(DAY, i.DueDate, GETDATE()) >= 0 -- Just get the on-times and lates.
)

SELECT  d.ItemID,
    d.DayDifference AS DaysLate,
    CASE WHEN s.StatusText IS NULL
        THEN 'Unknown'
        ELSE s.StatusText
        END AS StatusText
FROM    Data d
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Statuses s ON d.DayDifference = s.DayDifference
```

The results are as follows, when run today, 2018-12-06:

```
ItemID  DaysLate    StatusText
-------------------------------
1       5           5 Days Late
2       4           Unknown
3       0           On Time
4       0           On Time
7       2165        Unknown
8       1           1 Day Late
```

Note that this is a starting point, and probably needs to be molded to your exact use case.

Comment: Wow, that is awesome.  I had not considered getting the `DayDifference` and that is an excellent idea.

Comment: Of course, you'd need to somehow store a completion date of some sort, because if you keep checking against GETDATE(), everything will eventually show as late.

Comment: Yes, the actual table has a status, and once the status is closed, those are filtered out.